Automate adding nullclines to StreamPlot
I have the system
$$x' = x^2$$
$$y'= y(2x - y) $$
We can calculate the nullclines by solving the first equation for $y$, but since there is no $y$ it is just $x=0$. For the second equation, we get the two solutions as $y = 0$, $y = 2x$.
If we plot these, we get six regions as

We can also find the fixed point (using MMA 14.1) as
  DFixedPoints[{x'[t] == \[Minus]x[t]^2, y'[t] == y[t] (2 x[t] \[Minus] y[t])}, {x, y}, t]

We can then define the StreamPlot (the critical point is located at $(0,0)$) as
  StreamPlot[{x^2, y (2 x - y)}, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, 
   StreamPoints -> Fine, Epilog -> Style[Point[{{0, 0}}], Red, PointSize[Large]]]

My question is, can this process be automated where it finds the nullclines, critical points and then draws the StreamPlot in a single go by overlaying this information into one StreamPlot diagram that shows all this information at once?
I can plot each item and then use Show, but this is quite cumbersome.
This would be a nice feature to add to StreamPlot as options.

Maybe this:
splot // ClearAll;
splot // Options = {"StreamPlotOptions" -> {}, 
   "NullclineOptions" -> {}};
splot[vf_, xdom_, ydom_, OptionsPattern[]] :=
  With[{sopts = OptionValue["StreamPlotOptions"], 
    nopts = OptionValue["NullclineOptions"]},
   Show[
    ContourPlot[# == 0, xdom, ydom, nopts] & /@ 
     DeleteCases[
      Flatten[(FactorList /@ vf)[[All, All, 1]]], _?NumericQ],
    StreamPlot[vf, xdom, ydom, sopts]
    ]];

splot[{x^2, y (2 x - y)}, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4},
 "NullclineOptions" -> {ContourStyle -> Red},
 "StreamPlotOptions" -> {StreamPoints -> Fine, 
   Epilog -> Style[Point[{{0, 0}}], Red, PointSize[Large]]}]



That is excellent. Is there any way to add a different color for each critical point - in this case it would be a single point at the origin?

@Moo Graphics[{Green, Point[{xdom[[1]], ydom[[1]]}]/.Solve[vf == 0]}] or Graphics[Riffle[colors, {Point[{xdom[[1]], ydom[[1]]}] /. Solve[vf == 0]}]] after the StreamPlot. You have to decide what sort of syntax you want for specifying the colors, whether you want the colors to cycle through, etc. At some point it's easier to add things by hand than to create a Swiss-Army-Knife function.

Also, you'd have to match the order of the colors to the order of the solutions from Solve[]. It might be tricky to make it easy to use.

Thank you and I understand!
